# How to set html_options for a 'select' helper in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I have the next code to display my countries table in a select box:

```
f.select("country_id",  Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select a Country'})
```

and i want to set an 'onchange' action when a country es selected...
I've tried:

```
f.select("country_id",  Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select a Country',:onchange=>"alert('foo')"})
```

but nothing happens....

any help on this?

Thanks.
Mr. Nizzle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi format of this helper is

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

so try

```
f.select("country_id",  Country.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select a Country'},{:onchange=>"alert('foo')"})
```

and also check html output of your version

[Formbuilder#select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select)